# SignerRole in PAdES signatures with iText

Tags: java, itext, pades

Is it possible to embed a SignerRole value into a PAdES digital signature with iText? ... Why the PdfSignatureAppearance class does not expose a *setSignerRole("Jefe de Marketing")* method?

Comment: *Why the PdfSignatureAppearance class does not expose a setSignerRole("Jefe de Marketing") method?* - the implicit signing capabilities of the signature appearance class by itself dies not offer all options. For  special requirements please use a custom signature creation class.

Comment: SignerRole is only defined in PAdES-5, not in PAdES-2 nor in PAdES-3. Are you saying that you're using iText to create PAdES-5 signatures? In that case we want to talk to you, because we developed PAdES-5 functionality, but we don't know anyone who uses it (and not even Adobe Acrobat supports it).

Comment: Actually, I wasn't talking about PAdES for XML Content (PAdES-5). Specifically, my question is about a setSignerRole() or setClaimedRole() method based on the **signer-attributes** specified on [PAdES-3](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts%5C102700_102799%5C10277803%5C01.02.01_60%5Cts_10277803v010201p.pdf) (see clause 4.5.10) and [CAdES](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/101700_101799/101733/02.01.01_60/ts_101733v020101p.pdf) (see clause 5.11.3):  

*The signer-attributes attribute specifies additional attributes of the signer (e.g. role).*